# Change preview Memo2 using OnPreviewClick property of Memo1

Tags: fastreport

Suppose I want to change preview text on memo2 after clicking on memo1.    Let's say I have set property OnPreviewClick of memo1 to this:

```
procedure Memo1OnPreviewClick(Sender: TfrxView; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: Integer; var Modified: Boolean);
var
   s: String ;

begin

   s := TfrxMemoView( Sender ).Text  ;
   TfrxMemoView( Sender ).Text  := InputBox('BI-RADS', 'LT:', s ) ;     
   memo2.Text := TfrxMemoView( Sender ).Text ;

   Modified := True;  //this will update memo1 on preview but not memo2
    
end;
//----------------------------------------------------
```

Memo2.text contents will be changed but not displayed.

Anyone has an idea how to update preview so that Memo2 shows new data changed on event OnPreviewClick of memo1?

I need to do this from frx script.

Thank you,

Reinaldo.